# How can I search for domain class instances where a reference to another one is empty or matches a given value?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

To paraphrase a Grails example, I'm trying to fetch a list of books with no author.  The author could be anonymous, or simply not set (null).  So far I can search by value, I can search by null, but I can't seem to do both at once.  Using the Book and Author example, let's say I have the following books...

- "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer" by Mark Twain
- "O: A Presidential Novel" by Anonymous
- "Beowulf"

To find books by "Anonymous" I could do this...

```
Book.withCriteria {
  author {
    eq('name', 'Anonymous')
  }
}
```

Returns "O: A Presidential Novel"

All is well.  Now to find books with no author I can do this...

```
Book.withCriteria {
  isNull('author')
}
```

Returns "Beowulf"

That's fine too.  So to fetch both books I should 'or' them together...

```
Book.withCriteria {
  or {
    isNull('author')
    author {
      eq('name', 'Anonymous')
    }
  }
}
```

Returns "O: A Presidential Novel"

Why doesn't this return both books?  I'm using Grails 2.3.7 with Hibernate 3.6.10.16

Update:
I've found a query that works though I'm confused how it's different...

```
Book.withCriteria {
  or {
    isNull('author')
//  author {
//    eq('name', 'Anonymous')
//  }
    sqlRestriction('{alias}.author_id = (select author_id from authors where name = ?)', 'Anonymous')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, association queries like that map to an inner join at the SQL level. You can instead do a left outer join using `createAlias`:

```
def list = c.list {
  createAlias('author', 'a', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
  or {
    isNull('author')
    eq('a.name', 'Anonymous')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 3rd query results in this SQL statement (Grails 2.4.4, PostgreSQL):

```
select ... 
  from book b inner join author a on b.author_id = a.id 
    where (b.author_id is null or (a.name=$1))
```

So Grails emits an **inner join** which eliminates all books without an author. I don't know if it is possible that Grails emits an **outer join** here.

---

As for your 4th query using `sqlRestriction`, this results in a **sub select**:

```
select ...
  from book b 
  where (b.author_id is null or b.author_id = 
    (select author_id from author where name = $1))
```

So this works, but generally speaking sub selects might be slower than inner/outer joins.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Hibernate can be a mystical beast.  I've found that (in Oracle) the query optimizer builds the same query whether you use joins or subqueries, and personally I find subqueries easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do ? It seems that you get just the first result.

```
def c = Book.createCriteria() 
def list = c.list{
    or {
        isNull('author')
        author {
            eq('name', 'Anonymous')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  I don't understand why it only returns the first result when I would expect it to fetch both.